# How to configure nginx for multiple URL to which provide different resources

Tags: nginx

I've come across several examples demonstrating how to set up multiple domains with Nginx, but my URLs are serving resources that are distinct from the web page domain.

Are there any differences in terms of configuration requirements between these scenarios?

Comment: Perhaps english is not your first language - unfortunately your syntax is incorrect making it impossible to understand what the problem you are trying to solve is. And your explanation is very brief with no examples.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx has configuration for each domain and  as i suggested copy default configuration and change parameter of your domain at them (server blocks)As sample

`sudo cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/yourdomain.com`

Now open new configuration and set up your  paramter:

```
server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 index index.html index.htm; 
server_name localhost;
 location / { try_files $uri $uri/ =404; 
} 
}

Root is your directory
root /var/www/yourdomain.com/html;

Each statement need end with ;

Servername is your domain name
server_name your domain.com www.yourdomain.com;
```

Finally, need to configure your server block link and restart nginx

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/yourdomain.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/secounddomain.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

We can disable the default server block file by simply removing the symbolic link. It will still be available for reference in the sites-available directory, but it won’t be read by Nginx on startup:

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

We also need to adjust one setting really quickly in the default Nginx configuration file. Open it up by typing:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

We just need to uncomment one line. Find and remove the comment from this:

```
server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
```

Now, we are ready to restart Nginx to enable your changes. You can do that by typing:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Finally you need to set up your hostname in os

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost 
127.0.0.1 guest-desktop 
111.111.111.111 yourdomain.com
 111.111.111.111 secounddomain.com
```

Test you domain in the browser
http://yourdomain.com
If you had issue check nginx log and send error or startup log